# C-style struct name cause class template has already been declared as a non-class template with msvc

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors

Code bellow cause compilation error with msvc (x86 msvc v19.16),
but any other compiler accepts it without error (gcc, clang, icc).
You can see error here [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/0nt5PP) ,
the error is:

> [x86 msvc v19.16 #1] error C2989: 'RustStrView': class template has already been declared as a non-class template

about this line of code `template <bool PARAM> inline struct RustStrView Foo<PARAM>::f() {`

If I remove `struct` from `struct RustStrView` or make `Foo` not `template`
class all compiled without errors.
Is this bug in my code (clang/gcc/icc accepts it with `-std=c++11 -pedantic`)
or this is `msvc` bug?

Side note this is code is partly generated and it is not simple to teach generator 
to call type as `struct X` inside generated `C part` and `X` inside `C++`.

```
extern "C" {
struct RustStrView {
  unsigned not_important;
};

typedef struct FooOpaque FooOpaque;
struct RustStrView Foo_getName(const FooOpaque *const self);
}

template <bool> class Foo {
public:
  struct RustStrView f();

private:
  FooOpaque *p_;
};

template <bool PARAM> inline struct RustStrView Foo<PARAM>::f() {
  struct RustStrView s = Foo_getName(this->p_);
  return s;
}
```